# var_export does not handle circular references

Tags: php, laravel-8

Laravel: 8
Php: 8.1

We are facing an issue when caching the config with
PHP artisan config: cache.

It is a circular references-related issue and we have also faced issue-related closure that occurs when using the callback function in config files as suggested [here](https://github.com/exodusanto/Laravel-Admin/blob/master/docs/fields.md#editable-option).

> Error:
> ErrorException
> var_export does not handle circular references
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ConfigCacheCommand.php:63

```
     59▕ 
     60▕         $configPath = $this->laravel->getCachedConfigPath();
     61▕         
     62▕         $this->files->put(
  ➜ 63▕              $configPath, '<?php return '.var_export($config, true).';'.PHP_EOL
     64▕         );
     65▕ 
     66▕         try {
     67▕             require $configPath;

      +14 vendor frames 
  15  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

We have tried this but not working:

- We have tried to handle the error using Handler.php but it is not
  working
- Also, we have tried to remove the closure function from
  config/adminer.php but we have faced the following error:

> There are problems with your administrator.php config: The
> permission option must be a function

Please guide me on how to solve this error when configuring the cache.

Comment: Please post the error/code in question itself instead of images.

Comment: as to for "Is it possible to ignore this error when config cache or any way to handle this so error should not be reported?" question, please don't ignore/hide this type of errors.

Comment: Question update please check.